# Problem Starting and Stopping AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have a class in which I have an audio player.  In class B, I have a switch, from where I want to take control of play and stop of background music.

I am not able to stop and play music through switch.
this is my audio player at viewdidload of class A

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/bgmusic.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
if (audioPlayer == nil) NSLog([error description]);
else [audioPlayer play];
```

this is swtich of class B

```
-(IBAction) musicValueChanged:(id)sender{    
if (musicSwitch.on) { 
    isStopped = FALSE;
    firstViewController.player.currentTime = 0;
    [firstViewController.audioPlayer play];
 }else {
    [firstViewController.audioPlayer volume:0];
 }
}
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Where are you stuck, what have you tried? We are not psychic so you have to tell us how your design looks like.

Comment: this is my audio player at viewdidload of class A
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/bgmusic.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]]; 
 NSError *error;
 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
 audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
 
 [audioPlayer play];
 if (audioPlayer == nil)
  NSLog([error description]);
 else
  [audioPlayer play];

Comment: this is swtich of class B
-(IBAction) musicValueChanged:(id)sender{ 
 if (musicSwitch.on) {
  isStopped = FALSE;
  firstViewController.player.currentTime = 0;
  [firstViewController.audioPlayer play];
 }else {[firstViewController.audioPlayer volume:0];
}}

Comment: something wat i was trying.,.....its calling, but dont y,but its not doin anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the method is called and musicSwitch.on has a value, this should work:

-(IBAction) musicValueChanged:(id)sender{

```
if (musicSwitch.on) { 
    isStopped = FALSE;
    firstViewController.player.currentTime = 0;
    [firstViewController.audioPlayer play];
 }else {
    [firstViewController.audioPlayer stop];
 }
}
```

See the AVAudioPlayer docs.